# Cuda and pytorch memory usage

Tags: python, pytorch

I am using `Cuda` and `Pytorch:1.4.0`.

When I try to increase `batch_size`, I've got the following error:

`CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity;  2.74 GiB already allocated; 7.80 MiB free; 2.96 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)`

I haven't found anything about Pytorch memory usage.

Also, I don't understand why I have only 7.80 mib available?

Should I just use a videocard with better perfomance, or can I free some memory? FYI, I have a GTX 1050 TI, python 3,7 and torch==1.4.0 and my os is Windows 10.

Comment: Please don't post error messages as images. They can't be searched for by future visitors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, the following worked for me:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
# start training from here
```

Even after this if you get the error, then you should decrease the `batch_size`

Comment: To complement, one can check the GPU memory using `nvidia-smi` command on terminal. Also, if you're storing tensors on GPU you can move them to cpu using `tensor.cpu()`. I solve most of my problems with memory using these commands.