# Pytorch GPU memory allocation

Tags: python, gpu, pytorch

I have self-modified car recognition model, taken from https://github.com/Helias/Car-Model-Recognition. I use `Cuda` and `Pytorch:1.4.0`. But even though I tried to use the answer on my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60276672/cuda-and-pytorch-memory-usage/60277215#60277215), it still doesn't want to work with `BATCH_SIZE`>=7.The same thing happens:

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 20.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.74 GiB already allocated; 7.80 MiB free; 2.96 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

If I increase my `BATCH_SIZE`,pytorch gives me more, but not enough:
BATCH_SIZE=256

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 196.00 MiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.85 GiB already allocated; 93.80 MiB free; 2.87 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

BATCH_SIZE=512

```
CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 1.53 GiB (GPU 0; 4.00 GiB total capacity; 2.04 GiB already allocated; 927.80 MiB free; 2.06 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

My code is the following:
main.py

```
from dataset import torch, os, LocalDataset, transforms, np, get_class, num_classes, preprocessing, Image, m, s, dataset_main
from config import *

from torch import nn
from torch.optim import SGD
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision.models import resnet

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import unravel_index
import gc
import argparse
import cv2 as cv2
cuda_available = torch.cuda.is_available()
torch.cuda.set_device(0)
def train_model(model_name, model, train_loader, test_loader, lr=LEARNING_RATE, epochs=EPOCHS, momentum=MOMENTUM, weight_decay=0,):

    if not os.path.exists(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name):
        os.makedirs(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name)
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = SGD(model.parameters(), lr, momentum=momentum, weight_decay=weight_decay)
    loaders = {'train':train_loader, 'test':test_loader}
    losses = {'train':[], 'test':[]}
    accuracies = {'train':[], 'test':[]}

    #testing variables
    y_testing = []
    preds = []

    if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
        model=model.cuda()
    for e in range(epochs):
        for mode in ['train', 'test']:
            if mode=='train':
                model.train()
            else:
                model.eval()

            epoch_loss = 0
            epoch_acc = 0
            samples = 0

            try:
                for i, batch in enumerate(loaders[mode]):
                    # convert tensor to variable
                    x=Variable(batch['image'], requires_grad=(mode=='train'))
                    y=Variable(batch['label'])

                    if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
                        x = x.cuda()
                        y = y.cuda()

                    output = model(x)
                    l = criterion(output, y) # loss

                    if mode=='train':
                        l.backward()
                        optimizer.step()
                        optimizer.zero_grad()
                    else:
                        y_testing.extend(y.data.tolist())
                        preds.extend(output.max(1)[1].tolist())

                    if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
                        acc = accuracy_score(y.data.cuda().cpu().numpy(), output.max(1)[1].cuda().cpu().numpy())
                    else:
                        acc = accuracy_score(y.data, output.max(1)[1])

                    epoch_loss += l.data.item()*x.shape[0] # l.data[0]
                    epoch_acc += acc*x.shape[0]
                    samples += x.shape[0]

                    print ("\r[%s] Epoch %d/%d. Iteration %d/%d. Loss: %0.2f. Accuracy: %0.2f Learning Rate: %s" % \
                        (mode, e+1, epochs, i, len(loaders[mode]), epoch_loss/samples, epoch_acc/samples, 'test'))

                    if DEBUG and i == 2:
                        break
            except Exception as err:
                print ("\n\n######### ERROR #######")
                print (str(err))
                print ("\n\n######### batch #######")
                print (batch['img_name'])
                print ("\n\n")

            epoch_loss /= samples
            epoch_acc /= samples

            losses[mode].append(epoch_loss)
            accuracies[mode].append(epoch_acc)


            print ("\r[%s] Epoch %d/%d. Iteration %d/%d. Loss: %0.2f. Accuracy: %0.2f Learning Rate: %s" % \
                  (mode, e+1, epochs, i, len(loaders[mode]), epoch_loss, epoch_acc, 'test'))

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + ".pt")
    return model, (losses, accuracies), y_testing, preds

def test_model(model_name, model, test_loader):
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + ".pt"))

    if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
        model = model.cuda()

    model.eval()

    preds = []
    gts = []

    #debug
    i = 0

    for batch in test_loader:
        x = Variable(batch['image'])

        if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
            x = x.cuda()
            pred = model(x).data.cuda().cpu().numpy().copy()
        else:
            pred = model(x).data.numpy().copy()

        gt = batch['label'].numpy().copy()
        preds.append(pred)
        gts.append(gt)

        # debug
        if DEBUG:
            if i == 2:
                break
            else:
                i+=1

    return np.concatenate(preds), np.concatenate(gts)

def write_stats(model_name, y, predictions, gts, predictions2):
    if not os.path.exists(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name):
        os.makedirs(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name)

    acc = accuracy_score(gts, predictions2.argmax(1))
    cm = confusion_matrix(y, predictions)

    if DEBUG:
      score = "00 F1_SCORE 00"
    else:
      score = f1_score(y, predictions, average=None)

    file = open(str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + "_stats.txt", "w+")
    file.write ("Accuracy: " + str(acc) + "\n\n")
    file.write("Confusion Matrix: \n" + str(cm) + "\n\n")
    file.write("F1 Score: \n" + str(score))
    file.close()

def plot_logs_classification(model_name, logs):
    if not os.path.exists(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name):
        os.makedirs(RESULTS_PATH + "/" + model_name)

    training_losses, training_accuracies, test_losses, test_accuracies = \
        logs[0]['train'], logs[1]['train'], logs[0]['test'], logs[1]['test']

    plt.figure(figsize=(18,6))
    plt.subplot(121)
    plt.plot(training_losses)
    plt.plot(test_losses)
    plt.legend(['Training Loss','Test Losses'])
    plt.grid()
    plt.subplot(122)
    plt.plot(training_accuracies)
    plt.plot(test_accuracies)
    plt.legend(['Training Accuracy','Test Accuracy'])
    plt.grid()
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig(str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + "_graph.png")

def train_model_iter(model_name, model, args, training_set_loader, validation_set_loader, weight_decay=0):

    if args.train:
        model, loss_acc, y_testing, preds = train_model(model_name=model_name, model=model, train_loader=training_set_loader, test_loader=validation_set_loader, weight_decay=weight_decay)

        preds_test, gts = test_model(model_name, model=model, test_loader=validation_set_loader)

        write_stats(model_name, y_testing, preds, gts, preds_test)
        plot_logs_classification(model_name, loss_acc)

    gc.collect()
def main():
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    print('main')
    print(m, s)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='car model recognition')

    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input",      action="store",       dest="inp",   help="Take a sample image and classify it", type=str)
    parser.add_argument("-t", "--train",      action="store_true",                help="Run the training of the model")
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", action="store_true",                help="Update the train and test csv files with the new images in dataset, used this if you added new images in dataset")

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.preprocess:
        print ("Preprocessing..")
        preprocessing()
        print ("Preprocessing finished!")
    print(cuda_available)
    # directory results
    if not os.path.exists(RESULTS_PATH):
        os.makedirs(RESULTS_PATH)

    # Load dataset
    mean=m
    std_dev=s

    transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize((224,224)),
                                        transforms.ToTensor(),
                                        transforms.Normalize(mean, std_dev)])

    training_set = LocalDataset(IMAGES_PATH, TRAINING_PATH, transform=transform)
    validation_set = LocalDataset(IMAGES_PATH, VALIDATION_PATH, transform=transform)

    training_set_loader = DataLoader(dataset=training_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=8, shuffle=True)
    validation_set_loader = DataLoader(dataset=validation_set, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=8, shuffle=False)
    classes = {"num_classes": len(num_classes)}
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    resnet152_model = resnet.resnet152(pretrained=False, **classes)
    train_model_iter("resnet152", resnet152_model, args, training_set_loader, validation_set_loader)

    model_name="resnet152"
    model=resnet152_model

    if args.inp:
        print ("input: ", args.inp)

        image_path = args.inp
        im = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        im = transform(im)

        print (str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + ".pt")

        model.load_state_dict(torch.load(str(RESULTS_PATH) + "/" + str(model_name) + "/" + str(model_name) + ".pt"))

        if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
            model = model.cuda()
        model.eval()

        x = Variable(im.unsqueeze(0))

        if USE_CUDA and cuda_available:
            x = x.cuda()
            pred = model(x).data.cuda().cpu().numpy().copy()
        else:
            pred = model(x).data.numpy().copy()

        print (pred)

        idx_max_pred = np.argmax(pred)
        idx_classes = idx_max_pred % classes["num_classes"]
        print(get_class(idx_classes))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('main1')
    result = dataset_main()
    m = result[0]
    s = result[1]
    num_classes = result[2]
    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    main()
```

dataset.py

```
import numpy as np
import torch
import os
import cv2 as cv2

from torch.utils.data.dataset import Dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import transforms

from PIL import Image
Image.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
from os import path
from glob import glob
import random

from config import *

num_classes = { 'ford_explorer': 0, 'nissan_altima': 1, 'volkswagen_jetta': 2 }
# read mean and dev. standard pre-computed
m = 0
s = 0
def dataset_main():
    # dirs = glob(IMAGES_PATH + "/*/")
    # i = 0
    # for d in dirs:
    #     d = d.replace(IMAGES_PATH, "")
    #     d = d.replace("/", "")
    #     if " " in d:
    #         d = d.replace(" ", "_")
    #     num_classes[d] = i
    #     i+=1

    print ("Classes: ")
    print (num_classes)
    print ("")


    if os.path.isfile('./mean_devstd.txt'):
        m_s = open("mean_devstd.txt", "r").read()
        if "," in m_s:
            m_s = m_s.replace("\n", "")
            m_s = m_s.replace("tensor", "")
            m_s = m_s.replace("(", "")
            m_s = m_s.replace(")", "")
            m_s = m_s.split(",")
            m = torch.Tensor( [float(m_s[0]), float(m_s[1]), float(m_s[2])] )
            s = torch.Tensor( [float(m_s[3]), float(m_s[4]), float(m_s[5])] )
        return m, s, num_classes
def get_class(idx):
    #print (num_classes)
    for key in num_classes:
        if idx == num_classes[key]:
            return key

def preprocessing():
    train_csv = ""
    test_csv  = ""
    train_csv_supp = []
    test_csv_supp = []
    class_files_training = []
    class_files_testing  = []

    for key in num_classes:
        if " " in key:
            os.rename(IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key, IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key.replace(" ", "_"))
            key = key.replace(" ", "_")

        class_files = glob(IMAGES_PATH+"/"+str(key)+"/*")
        class_files = [w.replace(IMAGES_PATH+"/"+str(key)+"/", "") for w in class_files]
        class_files.sort()

        class_files_training = class_files[: int(len(class_files)*.66)] # get 66% class images fo training
        class_files_testing = class_files[int(len(class_files)*.66)+1 :] # get 33% class images fo testing

        for f in class_files_training:
            if "," in f or "#" in f or " " in f:
                tmp_f = f.replace(",", "")
                tmp_f = tmp_f.replace("#", "")
                tmp_f = tmp_f.replace(" ", "_")
                os.rename(IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key+"/"+f, IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key+"/"+tmp_f)
                f = tmp_f
            train_csv_supp.append(f + ","+str(key))

        for f in class_files_testing:
            if "," in f or "#" in f or " " in f:
                tmp_f = f.replace(",", "")
                tmp_f = tmp_f.replace("#", "")
                tmp_f = tmp_f.replace(" ", "_")
                os.rename(IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key+"/"+f, IMAGES_PATH+"/"+key+"/"+tmp_f)
                f = tmp_f
            test_csv_supp.append(f + ","+str(key))

    random.shuffle(train_csv_supp)
    random.shuffle(test_csv_supp)

    for t in train_csv_supp:
        train_csv += t + "\n"

    for t in test_csv_supp:
        test_csv += t + "\n"

    train_csv_file = open("train_file.csv", "w+")
    train_csv_file.write(train_csv)
    train_csv_file.close()

    test_csv_file = open("test_file.csv", "w+")
    test_csv_file.write(test_csv)
    test_csv_file.close()

    # Algorithms to calculate mean and standard_deviation
    print("Loading dataset...")
    dataset = LocalDataset(IMAGES_PATH, TRAINING_PATH, transform=transforms.ToTensor())
    print("Calculating mean & dev std...")

    m = torch.zeros(3) # Mean
    s = torch.zeros(3) # Standard Deviation
    for sample in dataset:
        m += sample['image'].sum(1).sum(1)
        s += ((sample['image']-m.view(3,1,1))**2).sum(1).sum(1)
    m /= len(dataset)*256*144    
    s = torch.sqrt(s/(len(dataset)*256*144))

    print("Calculated mean and standard deviation!")
    str_m = str(m[0])+","+str(m[1])+","+str(m[2])
    str_s = str(s[0])+","+str(s[1])+","+str(s[2])
    file = open("mean_devstd.txt", "w+")
    file.write(str(str_m)+","+str(str_s))
    file.close()
#preprocessing()

class LocalDataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self, base_path, txt_list, transform=None):
        self.base_path=base_path
        self.images = np.loadtxt(txt_list,delimiter=',',dtype='str') # use np.genfrom() instead of np.loadtxt() to skip errors

        self.transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        f,c = self.images[index]

        image_path = path.join(self.base_path + "/" + str(c), f)
        # image_path = path.join(str(c), f)
        im = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(image_path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        if self.transform is not None:
            im = self.transform(Image.fromarray(im))
        label = num_classes[c]

        return { 'image' : im, 'label':label, 'img_name': f }

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.images)
```

I can't understand, where my gpu is fluded, because everything seems to work fine.Is it just a problem in my video card? I have GTX 1050 TI and it should work well

Comment: I think that project uses ResNet-152 which is a 230MB model just in parameters. These docs say you have at least 27Gbs to train a batch of 128 at 224x224. https://github.com/albanie/convnet-burden/blob/master/reports/resnet-152.md

Comment: @Reactgular, thanks a lot. It works